# Inconsistent formatting of Go code?

Tags: go, gofmt

Here are some example code:

```golang
func main() {
    os.MkdirAll(outDir + id, 0755)
    os.Create(outDir + id + "/txt")
    os.OpenFile(outDir + id + "/" + ".tmp", os.OWRONLY|os_APPEND)
    os.Stat(outDir + id + "/.tmp")
}
```

The following is the output after formatting with either `go fmt` or pressing `Format` on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wX0wsWMLum):

```golang
func main() {
    os.MkdirAll(outDir+id, 0755)
    os.Create(outDir + id + "/txt")
    os.OpenFile(outDir+id+"/"+".tmp", os.OWRONLY|os_APPEND)
    os.Stat(outDir + id + "/.tmp")
}
```

Spaces in `os.MkdirAll()` and `os.OpenFile()` are removed while they are untouched in `os.Create()` and `os.Stat()`. I would expect that formatting to be identical.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12720

> gofmt uses spaces around binary expressions to express binding
> strength. Depending on nesting level, spaces are removed.
>
> You could also find these easily by searching for "gofmt inconsistent spaces".
> See also issue [#1206](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1206), [#1848](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1848), [#1861](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1861), [#7880](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7880), and [#11497](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11497).